# How to check whether two expressions are equivalent or not in java

Tags: java, pattern-matching, expression

I want to check whether two expressions are equivalent or not in `Java`. Let's say I have two expressions:
***exp 1:***

```
A && B && ( C || D)
```

***exp 2:***

```
B && ( C || D ) && A
```

I want to check whether these two expressions are equivalent or not.

What i mean by equivalent was if say we have two expressions then these two expressions must have same tokens(A , B, C, D) and the same relational operators between them. And should return the same values for all inputs. I do not want to consider the order how java execute these things. And what i need is a library or some java code snippet for doing so. Information about an algorithm is also fine.

Comment: What about trying it?

Comment: They are logically identical, but not performance-wise. As soon as either `A`, `B`, or `C || D` evaluates as `false`, then there is no point in checking the others and the VM won't do it. And the VM checks them in order, so the order matters performance-wise. So if for example `A` is likely to be `true`, and is heavy on performance, check it *last* like you're doing in the second example.

Comment: In general, you must check for all possible true and false values, which gives you 2^4 permutations, which is 16. However in this particular case they seem identical.

Comment: @abbath If i need to check an expression with say 100 more expressions for identical expressions then checking for all the possible true and false values will degrade the performance and even when the expression becomes complex this fails

Comment: Very simple: they are not identical. They would be identical if Java was side-effect free, but that isn't the case. The short circuiting is not the only reason - this expression is evaluated left to right so any side effects in one of the earlier subexpressions has an effect on the evaluation as a whole, and the order is different in your two expressions

Comment: Are you asking if the expressions are equivalent in the sense that they return the same result, given that A, B, C and D all are booleans? In that case, you want to evaluate the given expressions eqiuvalence from a mathematical point of view. This is not necessarily according to the language rules (since as already stated, the Java language does not view the expressions as equivalent). The best shot is probably to find a library doing this kind of thing. It will probably involve parsing the expressions as strings and the question is out of scope since it asks for a library doing this.

Comment: @pratik yeah I want to check whether two expressions are equivalent or not using some library or some algorithm. Sorry for my language. I will edit the question accordingly

Comment: I cannot understand SO people that slam questions closed because they don't understand the question.   OP here is a bit naive and does not understand that side effects and short circuit operators && and ||  will affect the question exactly as he posed it.  However, if you *reasonably* interpret his question for the formulas using & | ! ^ ( you get a perfectly good question, you can explain that, and everybody learns a little bit.

Comment: Secondly, unlike the "close" reason given, there is a perfect good answer:  first, take the two formulas F1 and F2, compute a new formula F3 = F1 <==> F2 ("implies both ways") or restricted to Java syntax F3 = !( F1 ^ F2).  Second, determine if F3 is a tautology, for which there are a variety of algorithms too big to write down in this margin.  ** but there is a perfectly good answer to this question **

Comment: I found out some thing that we can first check for all the tokens are same or not if they are same generate a truth table out of both the expressions and check whether all the return values are matching. But with this i am having a higher runtime. Can anyone suggest for a lesser runtime process rather than marking it as closed

Answer (score 4):

They are not due to the short evaluation. In Java, `A && B` returns false immediately when `A` is evaluated to `false`. It makes a difference e.g. when it comes to `Exceptions` or boolean methods that are not pure functions.

You can try the following experiment:

```
public class Test {

    public n = 0;
    public boolean A() {
        System.out.println("A");
        return false;
    }
    public boolean B() {
        System.out.println("B");
        return true;
    }
    public boolean C() {
        n++;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean D() {
        n = n*2;
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        if (test.A() && test.B()) { System.out.println("true"); }
        if (test.B() && test.A()) { System.out.println("true"); }
        if (test.C() && test.D()){}
        else {System.out.println(t.n);}
        t.n = 0;
        if (test.D() && test.C()){}
        else {System.out.println(t.n);}
        t.n = 0;
        boolean c = test.C();
        boolean d = test.D();
        if (d && c){}
        else {System.out.println(t.n);}
    }
}
```

It shows the consequences of a short evaluation connected with side effect.

Comment: hey i am looking for some algorithm or some package in java so that i can check for identical expressions

Comment: @Naruto *but they're not identical*.

Comment: @AndyTurner: I agree with you and xenteros; I think OP is a) a bit naive, and b) wants to do this for logical boolean formulas involving & and | rather than && and ||

Comment: @IraBaxter I think someone is switching from Prolog or Haskel to Java and want's it to behave as a toy :p

Comment: @xenteros or MATLAB/Octave/R: auto-magic languages can surely be convenient sometimes, but assuming the auto-magic features are going to work similar in all language is surely a bit naive. Conclusion Programming =! Maths

Comment: @IraBaxter it's not simply about short-circuiting, as ErwinBolwidt's comment above describes.

Comment: @AndyTurner: even if you ignore side effects, if the operands can throw exceptions they aren't equivelent.  yes, understood. You should give OP the benefit of doubt, and having explained the constraints, then answer the question that is left.

Comment: @xenteros: you closed the question because you *guessed he is switching from Prolog*?  That is simply stunning.  What else do you know about his life?

Comment: @IraBaxter I voted to close as this question is generally too broad for [so]. I gave an answer, but as the comments indicate, giving a full answer would be too long for [so]